# Kubernetes kubeconfig with service account token

Tags: kubernetes

I have a script that calls `kubectl -server $server --certificate-authority $ca --token $token get pod --all-namespaces` outside the cluster, where`$token` is from a service account `my-sa` (in namespace `my-ns`) with suitably restricted permissions under RBAC.

I now want to refactor this such that the script calls `kubectl --kubeconfig my-service.conf get pod --all-namespaces` instead, i.e. it should refer to a kubeconfig file instead of setting local parameters. This is in following Kubernetes' own conventions around its own kubeconfigs in `/etc/kubernetes`.

I've tried the following kubeconfig `my-service.conf`; `<CA_DATA>` is the base64-encoded content of `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`, `<SERVER>` is same as `$server`, and `<TOKEN>` is same as `$token`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <CA_DATA>
    server: <SERVER>
  name: my-cluster 
contexts:
- context:
  name: default-context
  context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    user: default-user
current-context: default-context
users:
- name: my-service
  user:
    token: <TOKEN>
```

`kubectl --kubeconfig /dev/null --server $server --certificate-authority /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --token $token get pods --all-namespaces` works on the command line, but `kubectl --kubeconfig my-service.conf get pod --all-namespaces` produces the following error message:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User
>   "system:anonymous" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the
>   cluster scope

So there still be something wrong with the [structure of my kubeconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount). Why did the client not [authenticate as](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) `system:serviceaccount:my-ns:my-sa`? What could be wrong?

**UPDATE** I was wondering whether it was perhaps inappropriate to use service account tokens outside the cluster (Kubernetes' own kubeconfigs use client certificates instead). But then the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) clearly states: "service account bearer tokens are perfectly valid to use outside the cluster".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your context config is referencing an inexistent credential...

Your credential is specified as `- name: my-service`, so your context should be:

```
- context:
  name: default-context
  context:
    cluster: my-cluster
    user: my-service       # instead of default-user
```