# How To login to azure kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

How can we login to a AKS cluster created , by using service account?
We are asked to execute kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin ......... but we are not aware how to use this and login to the created cluster in Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per ducemtaion:

> User accounts vs service accounts
>   Kubernetes distinguishes between the concept of a user account and a service account for a number of reasons:
>   **User accounts are for humans. Service accounts are for processes, which run in pods**.
>   User accounts are intended to be global. Names must be unique across all namespaces of a cluster, future user resource will not be namespaced. Service accounts are namespaced.
>   Typically, a cluster’s User accounts might be synced from a corporate database, where new user account creation requires special privileges and is tied to complex business processes. **Service account creation is intended to be more lightweight, allowing cluster users to create service accounts for specific tasks (i.e. principle of least privilege)**.
>   Auditing considerations for humans and service accounts may differ.
>   A config bundle for a complex system may include definition of various service accounts for components of that system. Because service accounts can be created ad-hoc and have namespaced names, such config is portable.

As an example:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: secret-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets-global
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: manager
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

you can find other helpful information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount/47776588#47776588), in [official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/), and Azure Kubernetes Service [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac)

Comment: how is this an answer, it doesnt show how to create the config (which is the hardest part)

Answer (score 9):

you can use this quick start tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster

basically you need to install kubectl:

```
az aks install-cli
```

and pull credentials for AKS:

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```