# How to specify Google service account in Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

I am deploying a Spring Boot application inside a Kubernetes pod on Google Cloud Platform.

I don't want to use the Compute Engine default service account in our pod.

How and where can we specify a Google service account for our pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This guide https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform#step_5_configure_the_application_with_the_secret helped me in setting the service account.

Answer (score 1):

Harold's suggestion to configure service account credentials in the pod as a secret is good and has been the recommended method for quite a while now. However, Google recently introduced [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) which allows you to link a k8s service account with a GCP IAM service account, you can then have your pod run with said k8s service account and use the IAM permissions that go with it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) and [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) referring to your service account, all you need to do is to create a context with apropriate service account as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount)

And then you just switch to this context

```
kubectl config use-context default-context
```

For more details on how to manage contexts check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#define-clusters-users-and-contexts)