# Minikube: kubectl doesn't use provided token permissions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Using minikube, when running the following command:

```
kubectl -v=11 --kubeconfig /dev/null --insecure-skip-tls-verify -s http://localhost:8001 --token "invalid" -n namespace get pods
```

I have an answer when I don't want one. And I don't know how it was authorized. Moreover, if I use a valid token with specific rights, these are not used.

[kubectl --token=$TOKEN doesn't run with the permissions of the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60083889/kubectl-token-token-doesnt-run-with-the-permissions-of-the-token) doesn't answer my question as I specified to used **/dev/null** as a config file.

Any idea ?

Comment: I get 401 with this command which is expected...and I am not on minikube

Comment: Why not use a `kube-proxy` ?

Comment: As the linked question, I guess that the authentication is done using client certificate.
But for a testing purpose, I do not wan't it involve, and cannot found an option on kubectl command to confirm this assumption and disabled it if confirmed.

Comment: kube-proxy is unrelated. kubectl command must have a way to use his token as specified.

Comment: Another odd thing, the associated permissions when the token is ignored are not the same as kubectl exec works without but doesn't with.

Comment: Where are you running minikube from? `8001` doesn't seem either the default port or the port that minikube would use for the kube-apiserver?

Comment: It looks like you are using `kubectl proxy` (guessing because localhost:8001). Can you confirm? @Neok

Comment: I confirm, so I can address to the Kubernetes apiserver

Comment: Ok, so with the minikube api endoint it works fine (didn't know about it). I'll definitly look up what kubectl proxy was doing.

Comment: Using kubectl proxy you are already authorized as other user and this is why it is working. Does this answer your question? @Neok

Comment: Definitely! Not within the scope of the question, but would you know where I can find out about this proxy user's permissions? (just to check up on it.)

Comment: You can run `kubectl auth can-i --list` to list your permissions. @Neok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to summarize the answer I provided in the comments.

The question was: *Why does running `kubectl -s http://localhost:8001 --kubeconfig /dev/null --token <invalid_token>` (where :8001 is a port opened by kubectl proxy) repoonds as if I was authorized, when it shouldn't beacause I set all possible authorization options to null or incorrect values?*

The answer is that `kubectl proxy` opens a port and handles all authorization for you so you dont have to. Now to access REST api of kubernetes all you need to do is to use `curl localhost:8001/...`. No tokens and certificates.

Because you are already authorized with `kubectl proxy`, using kubectl and pointing it to localhost:8001 is causing that it won't need to authorize and you won't need any tokens to access k8s.

---

As an alternative you can check what happens when you run the same but instead of connecting through `kubectl proxy` you use kubernetes port directly.

You mentioned that you are using minikube so by default that would be port 8443

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig /dev/null -s https://$(minikube ip):8443 --token "invalid" --insecure-skip-tls-verify get pods

error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

As you see now it works as expected.