# Azure AKS: Create a Kubeconfig from service account

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

What I want to achieve is this: I need to generate KubeConfig based on a service account token

The cluster is not integrated with Azure AD.

Here is how the generated Kubeconfig looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: <cluster-name>
  cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: <cluster certificate>
    server: https://[aks host]:443
contexts:
- name: <ctx>
  context:
    cluster: <cluster-name>
    namespace: <ns>
    user: <service account name>
current-context: <ctx>
users:
- name: <service account name>
  user:
    token: <service account token>
```

I am however ending up with this error `error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)`.

When I do `az aks get-credentials ...` the resulted kubeconfig has the `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data`. Of course, if I add those to the generated Kubeconfig above, it works fine, but still, that's the admin credentials. The service account is bound to a namespace with some RBAC rules in place.

The question is: is the token not enough for Azure AKS to authenticate? If it's not enough, what's another way of achieving that?

P.S: I don't want to use Azure DevOps Kubernetes Service Connection of type Service Account, I just need a KubeConfig.

**Update**:
Here is the same question: [How to create a kubectl config file for serviceaccount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount)

I have missed the "=" in the token -.-. That solved my problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount

Comment: @hariK yeah, I followed that one before posting my question, but I'm getting the error above.

Comment: @hariK, I made a stupid mistake by missing the "=" at the end of the token.