# How to generate admin.conf file for kubectl in Docker container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am working on running a project locally inside a Docker container with Linux-amd64 architecture. The start script runs the following command

```
kubectl create configmap -o yaml \
    --dry-run=true \
    --from-file ./configs/local/grafana \
    grafana-dashboards-source-config |
    kubectl apply -f -
```

which runs well on my MacOs but when run inside the Docker container, it fails with `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?` error. On browsing resources online, many posts suggested to use these commands to fix the issue

```
  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

but inside my Docker container I cannot find the `/kubernetes` directory and hence the `admin.conf` file.
I am using `COPY --from=lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:v1.10.3 /usr/local/bin/kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl` command in my Dockerfile to install kubectl and `kubectl version --client` returns with

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I wished to know what is the correct way to install kubectl while creating a Docker image so that I can find the `kubernetes/admin.conf` file, or if there is a way to generate it after kubectl is installed?

Comment: Usually I'd run `kubectl` commands like this as part of my deployment infrastructure (maybe implicitly in a Helm chart) and not part of my container startup.  Are you running this inside Kubernetes, or elsewhere?  Can you run `kubectl` from the host, and if so, where did its credentials come from?  Does a less-ancient version of `kubectl` do any better (1.10 is now nine releases behind)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the main idea is using kubectl inside a container in the cluster, you could use a `service account` to reach the Kubernetes API Server. You could follow the below steps in general.

- create a service account on your cluster with related permissions
- set the service account to your workload (deployment, stateful set, pod, etc.)
- set your config map to using the service account (/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/) this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount) could be useful.