# Kubectl forbidden error with service account & kubeconfig

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

TL;DR
Kubectl Forbidden error when using a service account with kubeconfig, but not other authentication methods. What could I did wrong ?

Apologies in advance if dupplicate, I couldn't find my specific scenario and tried all answers that popped on searches.

I have a self deployed Kubernetes 1.27 cluster, and aim to create a service account with all rights on a predefined set of namespaces. I want to create the kubeconfig file for this account to share with my team.

My user definition :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dev-team
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: dev-team-user-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: dev-team
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

Roles and bindings :

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: all-role
rules:
- apiGroups:
    - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dev-team-user-bindings
  namespace: dev
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: all-role
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dev-team
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
# copy previous rolebinding for each namespace
```

- I check my service account is working with :

```
kubectl get pods -n dev--as=dev-team
> NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
> pod-name   1/1     Running   5 (45h ago)   46h
```

And forbidden errors on other namespaces as expected.

Then, I created my kubeconfig by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770676/how-to-create-a-kubectl-config-file-for-serviceaccount)

And it looks like :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ###
    server: https://###:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: dev-team
    namespace: default
  name: dev-team@kubernetes
current-context: dev-team@kubernetes
preferences: {}
users:
- name: dev-team
  user:
    token: ###
```

- Issue, when i use my kubeconfig :

```
kubectl get pods -n dev --kubeconfig=kubeconfig
> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:dev-team" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "dev"
```

I add this in case it helps:

```
kubectl auth can-i --list --as=dev-team
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
                                                [/api/*]            []               [get]
                                                [/api]              []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]           []               [get]
                                                [/apis]             []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/livez]            []               [get]
                                                [/livez]            []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]        []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]          []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]           []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]           []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]

kubectl auth can-i --list --kubeconfig=kubeconfig
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs                     Resource Names   Verbs
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                                    []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                                    []               [create]
                                                [/.well-known/openid-configuration]   []               [get]
                                                [/api/*]                              []               [get]
                                                [/api]                                []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]                             []               [get]
                                                [/apis]                               []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]                            []               [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []               [get]
                                                [/livez]                              []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]                          []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]                            []               [get]
                                                [/openid/v1/jwks]                     []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []               [get]
                                                [/readyz]                             []               [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []               [get]
                                                [/version/]                           []               [get]
                                                [/version]                            []               [get]
                                                [/version]                            []               [get]
```